# How to read a .myox file using C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net, sqlconnection

A beginner here, trying to establish a connection to an `.myox` file using C# and read information from the file. The `.myox` file uses an SQL database. Below is the code am typing but am getting connection error, am pretty sure its the connection string which is incorrect but no matter how much i research I cant get anywhere.

```
string filepath = "C:\\Users\\Manu\\Desktop\\FileDesktop.myox";
string constring = "Data Source=" + filepath + ";";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select username from [user]", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

The error that I get is as follows

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I guess what am having trouble with is the parameters of the connection string. The file is always going to have a local path and not relative, but I don't know what else I should write or I am missing. If someone can direct me in right direction it would be very much helpful for me to continue learning.

Comment: What *is* a MYOX file? What makes you think its possible to connect to it as though it were an SQL Server (which is what your code assumes)?

Comment: .myox is a filetype from an accounting program 'myob accountright', am trying to read its database which uses sql. as i said am just a beginner trying to figure out first steps into coding.

Comment: Maybe change string constring = "Data Source=" + filepath + ";"; TO string constring = "Data Source=""" + filepath + """;"; Could be a File space issue - or single quote around.

Comment: SqlConnection et al are *not* a general purpose SQL library, they are  designed specifically to access Microsoft SQL Server instances which does not seem relevant here.  If you do not know precisely what type of database that file actually is you need to ask/research myob accountright for details or see if they have a data access API.